# My responsive slideshow only shows the first image

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, responsive-slides

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/responsiveslides.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
    speed: 1000,
    maxwidth:1060
  });
</script>


<div class="container">
    <ul class="rslides">
        <li><img src="graphics/img1.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/img2.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/img3.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>


.rslides {
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.rslides li {
    -moz-border-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -o-border-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    border-backface-visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

.rslides img {
    display:block;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    border:0;
}
```

This is a code I exactly copied from [website rslides](http://responsiveslides.com), but somehow it's not running correctly: it only shows the first image.

Comment: Are you sure your paths to your images are correct?

Comment: yes, it's all local. And one image is loading…

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have added the `responsive.min.js` correctly

Also  initialize the plugin in `document.ready function` so it loads completely,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
        speed: 1000,
        maxwidth:1060
    });
});
```

I have tried in `fiddle` and it works.

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/pYzfW/

**Update Full code**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
/*! http://responsiveslides.com v1.54 by @viljamis */

.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $.getScript('http://responsiveslides.com/responsiveslides.min.js',function(){
      $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
       speed: 1000,
      maxwidth:1060
    });});
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <ul class="rslides">
         <li><img src="http://responsiveslides.com/1.jpg" alt=""/></li>
         <li><img src="http://responsiveslides.com/2.jpg" alt=""/></li>
         <li><img src="http://responsiveslides.com/3.jpg" alt=""/></li>
      </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Before check it needs `net connection` for both `js` `jquery and responsive js`

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't work, because the website is not online. So I'll create a subfolder on my server to try it out. Many thanks for the jsFiddle!

Comment: I don't think, there should be any problem with localhost.

Comment: Agree, but then I really don't understand.

Comment: Check the above answer to test it, this code is not necessary to check `online`. But it needs 2 js `jquery and responsive`

Comment: checked, both files are where they need to be…

Comment: Update: the slideshow still didn't work, so finally I looked for another jquery responsive slideshow. Found one did work: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/  Thanks anyway!

Comment: @CindyvanOsch I have given you full code. Now, what is the issue I can't say. If you copy my `html` and paste in a `new html page`, then you can find it is working. Please check the `js` is loaded or not. Because I used `CDN` for `jquery` and `responsiveslides`, so works only when your system has **net enabled**

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap your responsiveSlides initialization in a [jQuery onready callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3). Otherwise, that code is being called before the elements exist, so the intialization has no effect.

```
$(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
        speed: 1000,
        maxwidth:1060
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for looking! It still doesn't work, must be something silly…