# ResponiveSlides Not Working - Any Browser

Tags: jquery, slideshow, responsive-slides

I've been unable to get [ResponsiveSlides](http://responsiveslides.com/) to work on any browser so far (Chrome, Firefox, Safari). I pretty much used the exact code from the site, but here's what I have:

In the header:

```
<head>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js" ></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    speed: 1000,
    maxwidth: 775
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Immediately after, in the body:

```
<div id="content" >
<div id="header" >
    <ul class="rslides" >
        <li><img src="images/slider/1.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider/2.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider/3.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider/4.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider/4.png" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the css (at the very top):

```
/* BEGIN SLIDESHOW */

.rslides {
position:relative;
list-style-type:none;
list-style-position:initial;
list-style-image:initial;
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.rslides li {
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
display:none;
width:100%;
left:0;
top:0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
position:relative;
display:block;
float:left;
}

.rslides img {
display:block;
height:auto;
float:left;
width:100%;
border-image:initial;
}

/* END SLIDESHOW */
```

There is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191646/my-responsive-slideshow-only-shows-the-first-image) about this that has no answer. I believe I'm having the same issue - where only the first image is shown and the slideshow doesn't play. I found a few other fairly similar issues but nothing has a solution or the situation was different.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides(

{
    auto: true,
    speed: 1000,
    maxwidth: 775
});

  });
</script>
```

Instead of  `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 0):

Try This With Double Code..

```
 <script>
          $(function () {
        $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
        "auto": true,
        "speed": 1000,
        "maxwidth": 775
        });
});
    </script>
```